# IE 9 list elements not displaying horizontally

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a simple list of `li` elements which display correctly (horizontally) in IE10, Chrome, etc. They don't display horizontally in IE9 though.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="legal-icons-footer">
     <ul>
      <li>
        item
      </li>
      <li>
        item
      </li>
      <li>
        item
      </li>
      <li>
        item
      </li>
      <li>
        item
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.legal-icons-footer li{
      display: inline;
}
```

Is there a hack or work-around for IE9?

Comment: List items belong in list elements (`<ol>`, `<ul>`, or `<menu>`). Can you get your styling working without the `div`?

Comment: I accidentally left the `<ul></ul>` tag out, but its still an issue in IE9

Comment: Add this doctype `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Comment: Already have the dtd in place. That's not the issue.